# Excel - from text to rows

Tags: excel, cell, rows

I have different sentences of different length, such as:

```
 They explained why we should eat fruit every day.
 He was asked to fill in a questionnaire before starting the interview.
```

I would like to have each word in a row, in the same column, like this:

```
 They
 explained
 why
 we
 should
 eat
 fruit
 every
 day
 He
 was
 asked
 to
 fill
 in
 a
 questionnaire
 before
 starting
 the
 interview
```

Is there any formula I could use to solve it?
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** and **A2**, in **A3** enter:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1 & " " & A2),"."," "))
```

in **A4** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$3," ",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

With data in **A1** through **A95**, I would **daisy-chain** the concatenation in column **B** *(I dislike long formulas)*.

So in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **B2** enter:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B1 & " " & A2),"."," "))
```

and copy down.  Then I would apply the single-word parsing formula to **$B$95** rather than **$A$3**

Comment: Gary's Student, thank you for your answer. With only two sentences it works perfectly. I have 95 sentences. I tried to do this: `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1 & " " & A2 &" "&A3&" "&A4&" "&A5&" "&A6&" "&A7&" "&A8&" "&A9&" "&A10&" "&A11&" "&A12&" "&A13&" "&A14&" "&A15&" "&A16&" "&A17&" "&A18&" "&A19&" "&A20&" "&A21&" "&A22&` until `&A88&" "&A89&" "&A90&" "&A91&" "&A92&" "&A93&" "&A94&" "&A95),"."," "))` - it doesn't accept me to write it down in the answer as too long. And then on A97 I used `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$96," ",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-904,999))`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @dede  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Gary's Student, thank you very much for the edit. I followed it, but still I obtain `#VALUE`. I have my 95 sentences in column A, I copied the first sentence as you said in cell B1. Then from B2 I entered, as you said, `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B1 & " " & A2),"."," "))`until cell B95, in which I have `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B94 & " " & A95),"."," "))`. In cell B96 I have: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($B$95," ",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))`. Am I doing something wrong?